# Does Spring integeration kafka support dynamic topic creation

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am a newbie to spring integeration kafka and I understand kafka-oubound-channel adapter. But is there a way i can create topics progamattically without having to setup in context xml?

ie: based on my message to transformer i would like to post message to kafka topic created for this message type.

**Update:**

Below is what I ended up doing. Will welcome any better solution.

```
    <int:channel id="inputForSolrPublish"></int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="inputForSolrPublish"
    ref="solrMasterListRouter" >
```

-->

```
 private void postMessageToMasterSpecifcTopics(final List<String> topicNames,
                                              final String brokerList,
                                              final Message<?> message) throws Exception {

    for (String topicName : topicNames) {
        createProducerContext(topicName,
                              brokerList).send(topicName,
                                               message.getHeaders()
                                                      .get(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY),
                                               message);

    }

}

private KafkaProducerContext<String, String> createProducerContext(final String topicName,
                                                                   final String brokerList) throws Exception {
    KafkaProducerContext<String, String> kafkaProducerContext = new KafkaProducerContext<String, String>();
    AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder<String> kafkaReflectionEncoder = new AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder<>(String.class);
    AvroSpecificDatumBackedKafkaEncoder<String> kafkaSpecificEncoder = new AvroSpecificDatumBackedKafkaEncoder<>(String.class);
    // Encoder<String> encoder = new
    // org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringEncoder<String>();

    ProducerMetadata<String, String> producerMetadata = new ProducerMetadata<String, String>(topicName);
    producerMetadata.setValueClassType(String.class);
    producerMetadata.setKeyClassType(String.class);
    producerMetadata.setValueEncoder(kafkaSpecificEncoder);
    producerMetadata.setKeyEncoder(kafkaReflectionEncoder);
    producerMetadata.setAsync(true);

    Properties props = buildProducerConfigProperties();
    ProducerFactoryBean<String, String> producer = new ProducerFactoryBean<String, String>(producerMetadata,
                                                                                           brokerList,
                                                                                           props);
    ProducerConfiguration<String, String> config = new ProducerConfiguration<String, String>(producerMetadata,
                                                                                             producer.getObject());
    kafkaProducerContext.setProducerConfigurations(Collections.singletonMap(topicName,
                                                                            config));
    return kafkaProducerContext;
}

private Properties buildProducerConfigProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms",
              "3600000");
    props.put("message.send.max.retries",
              "5");
    props.put("tsend.buffer.bytes",
              "5242880");
    return props;

}
```

Comment: Hi @Harshjgs, Please tell me the usage of `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY` field. I am not able to find its purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that at runtime. See `TopicUtils.ensureTopicCreated`.

You can add it like a `<service-activator>` as one more subscriber (the first one) to the `<publish-subscribe-channel>` for sending messages. Something like this:

```
<publish-subscribe-channel id="sendMessageToKafkaChannel"/>

<service-activator input-channel="sendMessageToKafkaChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" order="1"
   ref="creatTopicService" method="creatTopic"/>

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter channel="sendMessageToKafkaChannel" order="2"/>
```

Accept in that `creatTopic` the whole message and extract all required parameter from the message or during injection phase, e.g. inject `ZookeeperConnect` to extract `getZkConnect()` for the first `zkAddress` `ensureTopicCreated` argument.

But you should understand that you can't have an `<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter>` without existing topic on the Kafka. So, I'm not sure how you are going to get deal with messages in those dynamically-created topic in the future. Although `<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>` may work for that case...

Comment: thanks Aetem. I ended doing something very similar to your suggestion. let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Having the `<int-kafka:producer-context>` config you can add new `ProducerConfiguration` to the existing using its `getProducerConfigurations()` From other side you can use the single `<int-kafka:producer-configuration>` and always send messages to the `<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>`. That's because you use in your code the same `brokerList`, as well as all other `ProducerConfiguration` options.

Comment: Thnks. make sense will do those spring based cleanups. and would do more component reuse.